# Rails Ancestry gem: ensuring parent node exists when saving a node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I am trying [the Ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) for the first time today as part of a content management system, and would like to be able to create nodes and join them together in a tree manually. In other words, the context doesn't dictate what the parent of any new node is, unlike the many threaded discussion examples that everyone has read.

At the moment, when I try to save (create or update) a node with a parent_id that doesn't exist ("4"), I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TreesController#update
Couldn't find Tree with 'id'=4
```

I want to have any nodes that refer to non-existent parents to be assigned to have no parent. How do I do that?

Here is the relevant part of trees_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @tree = Tree.new(tree_params)
    if @tree.save
        redirect_to trees_url, notice: "Tree was successfully created"
    else
        render :new
    end     
  end

  ...

  private

  def tree_params
    params.require(:tree).permit(:name, :value, :note, :parent_id)
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a week of research I managed to get it sorted. Here is the solution for those of you that hit the same obstacle:

```
  def create
    parent_exists = Tree.exists?(params[:tree][:parent_id])
    if !parent_exists
        params[:tree][:parent_id] = nil
        note = "Parent node didn't exist so set to nil."
    end
    @tree = Tree.new(tree_params)
    if @tree.save
        redirect_to trees_url, notice: "Node was successfully created. " + note.to_s
    else
        render :new, notice: "There was an error saving this node. Please try again."
    end
  end
```